# SwiftUI when animating the button with scaleEffect, lines remain along the border of the initial size

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I am trying to create a button with an bounce animation affect on tap using SwiftUI. The code below does the correct animation and everything works fine in preview. But when running the same code in the simulator after the animation is done, I always end up with lines that are left at the original size boundary. What could be the problem?

XCode 13.3, iOS 15.4, Simulator iPhone 12 mini

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContinueButton: View {
    let title: String
    @State var isLoading: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            print("")
        }) {
            Text(title)
                .font(.system(size: 20)).bold().italic()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .opacity(isLoading ? 0 : 1)
                .overlay(
                    ProgressView()
                        .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .white))
                        .opacity(isLoading ? 1 : 0)
                )
        }

        .buttonStyle(ScaleButtonStyle())
        .disabled(isLoading)

    }
}

public struct ScaleButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    public func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(height: 56)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: 56)
            .background(Color.redOctober)
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95 : 1)
            .animation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 1,
                                            stiffness: 350,
                                            damping: configuration.isPressed ? 8.35 : 5.35,
                                            initialVelocity: 0.8))
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not reproduced with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4. Which env did you use? BTW this might depend on other layout, so please show how do you test it. Also try to use instead `.animation(... , value: configuration.isPressed)`

Comment: XCode 13.3, iOS 15.4, iPhone 12 mini. Just added to the view inside of the `VStack`

Comment: `value: configuration.isPressed` didn't change anything

Comment: works fine in Simulator on iPhone 12 Pro, but reproducible on iPhone 12 mini 

Comment: Change color of what you have got around the button to see if it comes from another element. In preview the button is alone.

Comment: This may be an issue just with the iPhone 12 mini simulator. We have seen bugs like this before that are not reproducible on other simulators or real devices.